# why am I not seeing "403: access denied" in Cloud Loggin

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I try to copy a file to Google Cloud Storage and I get an error "403 Access denied". Why can I not see this in Log Explorer?

It would be great to see the error message in Cloud Logging as this would give me the information WHO tried to access the Cloud Storage - my operating system user or the compute engine service account.

Comment: A work-around that enabled me to find out the principal was to do gsutil ls, it resulted in an AccessDeniedException that spelled out which service account was denied access.

Comment: The Audit logs will show the API access. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk I have posted community wiki answer. Feel free to update it if anything is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as a community wiki. As you posted a comment, posting the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out

As you found out that the error `403 Access denied` you are getting  is because that one of your service account  doest  have proper permissions.Using `gsutil ls` to trigger an access denied error and identify the service account or principal that was denied access

Also, Ensure that you have the necessary roles to view logs in the Logs Explorer.
For more information on how to check `WHO tried to access the Cloud Storage` check this [Logs Explorer doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface#getting_started) & [Routing and storage overview doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview).